# Alternatives to Windows Search using Advanced Query Syntax or similar

Tags: windows-search

Windows Desktop Search in Windows 10 from within Explorer seems wonky.  In recent Win 10 versions, Microsoft has chosen to no longer show the Search tab in an Explorer window until a search has already started, which makes applying filters a little clunky.  On my machine, even after a search is begun, it sometimes doesn't show up at all.  I realize MS would rather have one search from the search bar near the start menu now, but performance there seems even worse.

Searches results from Desktop Search are also unpredictable.  Sometimes a search can be started and the machine will go to work, showing a progress bar that takes a long time and doesn't find anything.  Then, when the same search is re-run, a result will pop up almost instantly...or sometimes not.  The UI also seems slow to respond to input in general.

Are there alternatives that allow the same levels of granular specificity as Windows Search using AQS does, but that perform better and that provide more repeatable results?  Maybe a command line version of Windows Search?  Open source search applications?

Thanks

Edit: adding more specificity:

I want to search by properties typically specified with AQS, not by ASCII text matches.  I am looking for metadata, like "kind:contacts jobtitle:CFO" or "documentmanager:TimD" that a simple text search would not likely reveal.  I was hoping something other than Windows Search could do this, or that there was another, faster & more reliable interface to it than Windows Explorer or the Windows search bar.

Comment: "_Sometimes a search can be started and the machine will go to work, showing a progress bar that takes a long time and doesn't find anything. Then, when the same search is re-run, a result will pop up almost instantly_" Specific to this portion, that sounds like an indexing issue - when searching within a directory that isn't indexed, search will initially take longer, then when a search of the same directory occurs again, it'll be fast because it's already been indexed. That doesn't explain why a result wouldn't populate during the first search, but would on the second

Answer (score 1):

[Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) might be what you are looking for.

[image: "Everything" is a filename search engine for Windows]

It supports [RegEx](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/searching#regex), has a UI for [advanced search](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/searching/#advanced_search) and a huge list of operators for filtering results based on file types, file size, folders, media type, date and more.
You can view the search syntax [here](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/searching/).

The app is small, comes with an installer and a portable version, and is being maintained with regular updates.

For more software recommendations, post a question on SE's [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) website.

Comment: Thank you for recommending Everything.  It does appear to be a wonderfully fast search program!  I put it on all my machines when I saw how amazingly fast it is.  But I was hoping for a way to search by the same kinds of super-granular filter properties that Microsoft's AQS offers, like "kind=music" or "kind:contacts jobtitle:CFO".  Everything is amazing, to be sure, and maybe it has some of the functionality I'm after and I just don't know yet.  It certainly gets me closer.  I'll have to investigate whether I can search by AQS filters using RegEx somehow? Thank you.